# Extra text'n'image field in a page

Tags: custom-field

Hi there dudes and dudettes!

I have been serching around for a bit, but havent quite found my answer as of yet.
I want to add extra fields for products on a webpage.
Just as simple as a small image, some text and a button/link for the product page.
Just like the attached picture. Where the white areas are text, and the red ones are images.

"Hope" this isnt answered in the past. And if so, I would really appreciate a link:D

Thank you in advance! 
[image: Like this!]

Comment: Are you using WooCommerce or any other plugin for displaying products?

Comment: I'm not I'm afraid.. I am planning to make a netshop eventually, should I start mapping them into WooCommerce at once?

Comment: I'd prefer using WooCommerce from now. It would be easier managing your products. Come back again after installing and you can see a help from me since it contains hooks and filters to add additional codes.